# postsharp 3 introduce/remove constructor aspect

Tags: constructor, postsharp, aspect, compile-time-weaving

I'm evaluating Postsharp 3.0 and would like to know if there is a way to introduce and/or remove constructors.

The use case is to remove all public parameterless constructors, and introduce a private paramterless one.

Thanks in advance,

Kavan

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to remove or introduce constructors using PostSharp.

Comment: Not even with the SDK?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible with the SDK, but since it is neither documented neither supported, we don't mention it as a possible solution. Basically, what you want is to change the visibility of all public parameterless constructors to internal, if I understand properly.